# Alinear botón a la derecha del Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

Trato de alinear un botón a la derecha del tamaño del layout en que se encuentra. He probado con el Gravity y no me lo hace. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutEditText"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonInvertirTick"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/success"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tendrías que usar `android:layout_gravity`, ya que esta es la que marca la posición de un elemento respecto al elemento padre, en vez de `android:gravity`, que indica la posición de su vista (por ejemplo, el texto que tengas en el botón, que pertenece a la vista del mismo).

Comment: Gracias por el aporte ;)